# Append scaling issues. When I append an object it's smaller than the original

Tags: append

I noticed that when I append an object from one blend file to another, the appended object is smaller than the original. I have an object measuring about 9.3 cm and when I append it to another blend file it's only about 8.8. Wish I would have caught this before as it cost me money for a now unusable 3D print. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That should not happen. Could you add more info? I'm not abe to reproduce this issue. Is your object parented to something else?

Comment: Did you apply (Ctrl A) the scale in the source file?

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the late reply I was at work all day. So I just checked and yes apparently it had a parent this whole time. Upon removing the parent my object shrunk in the original blend file to the same size was getting appended as. I had duplicated it and moved it to a new layer. The armature parent no longer had any effect on the new mesh and so I thought it was free of any parent. Thank you both for your help. Carlo if you switch your comment to an answer I'll mark it as correct